# @media_query no funciona al tener un scroll vertical

Tags: html, css, frontend

Tengo web donde me funciona el css normal pero al agregar mas contenido me aparece el scrooll como en cualquier web, el problema me surge que al tener ese scrool el @media_query se distorciona osea si le puse un max-width:645px ya no es 645px ahora agarra a unos 629px pero si borro contenido haciendo que desaparezca el scroll vuelve a funcionar a los 645px. adjunto evidencias.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora donde la imagen deja de captar el efecto es a los 629px
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Bien ahora al quitar contenido y reducir el scrool sucede esto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego de mucho inspeccionar me di cuenta de que si uso esta parte del inspector de elementos me agarra como deberia de ser, pero mi duda surge en porque no me reconoce el codigo en el navegador de la primera forma? Si siempre he trabajado con ello y no tuve problemas,o tengo algun codigo que esta alterando el resultado,quiero hacer enfasis que todo mi codigo esta en estatito osea es HTML y CSS puro:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Yo también he observado ese cambio. Y digo cambio porque, como tú, no había reparado en ello antes, por lo que creo que es algo relativamente nuevo. Sobre todo porque [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8146874/issue-with-css-media-queriesscrollbar) comentaban en 2015 que, mientras que Firefox y Ópera sí contaban los 15 píxeles del scrollbar en los media queries, los navegadores con base Webkit, como Chrome, no lo hacían. Y ahora parece que sí. Tal vez se haya convertido en el estándar.

Pero vamos, especulo, porque no he encontrado información actual específica sobre esto.

Answer (score 0):

Es medio confuso, dice que DESDE los 381 px (para arriba), esté de color verde, pero despues dice que de 645px para abajo, esté de color rosa, no entendí lo del scroll, pero intentá poner en los 381px en vez de min-width, poné max-width a ver que pasa. Saludos.

Comment: Nada lo cambie y sigue como si alguien le estaria restando piexeles a ese media query

Comment: Podrías pasar el codigo completo?